# How to extract the "Requires(pre)" field of an RPM package?

Tags: linux, rpm

I have a spec file for an RPM that contains both "Requires" and "Requires(pre)" in it. Basically, something like:

```
Requires: /lib/lsb/init-functions, /sbin/iptables
Requires(pre): zip
```

If I run

```
rpm -pqR package.rpm
```

I get, among others, the three specified requirements. I'd like a way to obtain only the pre-dependencies (the "Requires(zip)") for an automatic conversion to Debian "Pre-Depends". I've also tried with (some of) the keys that rpm --querytags has to offer, with no success.

Any suggestions?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the `-v` option, `rpm` shows that information.  For example,

```
$ rpm -qpR diffstat-1.61-1.x86_64.rpm
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)
zlib
zlib-devel
```

but using `-v`

```
$ rpm -qpR -v diffstat-1.61-1.x86_64.rpm
auto: libc.so.6()(64bit)
auto: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
auto: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
auto: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
rpmlib: rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib: rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib: rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib: rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
auto: rtld(GNU_HASH)
manual: zlib
pre: zlib-devel
```

Comment: That works perfectly. With a bit of parsing I can extract the dependencies and pre-dependencies just fine.